# PHP parse string as condition operator

Tags: php

I have a form where the user can create their own condition. E.g

```
<select name="operator">
    <option value="==">(==) Equal</option>
    <option value="!=">(!=) - Not Equal</option>
    <option value="&gt;">(&gt;) - Greater than</option>
    <option value="&lt;">(&lt;) - Less than</option>
    <option value="&gt;=">(&gt;=) - Greater than or equal to </option>
    <option value="&lt;=">(&lt;=) - Less than or equal to </option>
</select>
```

How could I parse the operator so that its actually a string but php interprets it as a condition operator?

```
if($column $operator $value){

}
```

The long winded way of doing it would be something like this:

```
switch($operator){
    case '!=':
        if($column != $value){

        }
    break;
    case '<=':
    case '&lt;=':
        if($column <= $value){

        }
    break;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a variable as an operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263311/using-a-variable-as-an-operator)

Comment: "Short" answer: __use "long" way__. Do not use `eval()`.

Answer (score 3):

The only way to do this would to be use [`eval`](https://www.php.net/eval) which evaluates a string as PHP code.

Using `eval` is generally not recommended for security reasons. Your current approach using `switch` is the best solution. The only other option is using `if` statements in a similar manner.

Answer (score 1):

**Indirect answer**

Although PHP supports execution of arbitrary code, I would advise you *not* to do it. There are alternatives!

For this case I would advise the [Strategy Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern). It's a pattern that allows behavior to be selected at runtime. IMHO exactly what you need.

It may be a bit more work to set up than a `switch` statement, but it's far more flexible and maintainable.

**Direct answer**

You can use `eval()` ([php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php)) for this:

```
if (eval("return \$column $operator \$value;")) {
}
```

But I *strongly* discourage you from doing this:

> The eval() language construct is very dangerous because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. Its use thus is discouraged. If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

I can't express this enough: *don't use `eval()`!*

Comment: +1 for recommending the Strategy Pattern here! But please put the eval() paragraph below your really really good point so nobody is even tempted to use the eval approach.

Comment: @thomas-david-plat Et voilà!