# Fetch PHP operator from MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, comparison, operators

What i'm trying to do seemed simple but I'm struggling to get it to work.

What I would like is to fetch a comparison operator from mysql and use in PHP but it doesn't seem to work at the moment.

I currently have the below:

```
if($currentDebtRatio.$row['operator'].$row['value'])    {echo "Test"}
```

This outputs as:

```
0>2
```

The problem is that the text displays even though the criteria doesn't appear to have been met.

If I hard code as:

```
if($currentDebtRatio > $row['value'])   {echo "Test"}
```

Then it isn't displayed.

Is it possible to store operators in mysql?

Comment: $currentDebtRatio. '>' .$row['value']  works for me!!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP parse string as condition operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22218263/php-parse-string-as-condition-operator). Also see [Using a variable as an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263311/using-a-variable-as-an-operator).

Comment: @showdev perfect - thanks