# PHP calculations with numbers and operators from variables

Tags: php

I have set these variables in PHP:

```
$settings["operator"] = '/';
$settings["figure"] = '0.6';
```

I then want to use the above on another variable to work out a calculation, which will end up being:

```
$total = ($var->price / 0.6);
```

I tried this:

```
$total = ($var->price $settings["operator"] $settings["figure"]);
```

But I'm getting an error because the code is not correct:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$settings' (T_VARIABLE)'

How can I use these variables to create my calculation?

Comment: You can use a `switch` to determine what to do based on the value of `$settings["operator"]`.  Something like `switch($settings["operator"]){ case '/': $total = ($var->price / 0.6); break; case '*': $total = ($var->price * 0.6); break; }`

Comment: [How to make a calculator in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12692727/how-to-make-a-calculator-in-php)

Comment: I feel like the php side of s.o. is full of duplicate questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to make switch or something similar.

```
switch($settings["operator"]){
  case "/":
    $total = $var->price / $settings["figure"];
    break;

 case "+";
   $total = $var->price + $settings["figure"];
   break;
 //add others under here
}
```

Comment: Just FYI, your case is / but you use *

Comment: @AbraCadaver Ah typed to fast, edited it! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with `eval()`.  It is great for many things,  you just have to know how to use it safely.  I wouldn't use a switch as it's not as flexible:

```
$allowed = array('/', '*', '-', '+');

if(in_array($settings["operator"], $allowed) && is_numeric($settings["figure"])) {
    eval('$result = ' . $var->price . $settings["operator"] . $settings["figure"] . ';');
}
echo $result;
```

Or maybe more readable:

```
 eval("\$result = {$var->price} {$settings['operator']} {$settings['figure']};");
```

Answer (score 0):

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2263319/6256153) by [Kristopher](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1497409/kristopher):

> [...] that syntax isn't available. The best you could do would be an eval(), which would not be recommended, especially if the $e came from user input (ie, a form) [...]

Rather use switch as he suggested:

```
$settings["operator"] = '/';
$settings["figure"] = '0.6';

switch ( $settings["operator"] ) {
  case '/':
    $total = $var->price / $settings["figure"];
    break;

// ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't support variable operators in this way. It's essentially trying to handle the following `$total = (number string string)` hence the syntax error.

PHP does support [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) so you could try the following :

```
//poke around the PHP manual and you will find functions that do this  kind of thing.
function doDiv($a,$b) {
    return ($a/$b):
}

$settings['someMathFunction'] = 'doDiv';
$settings['figure] = 0.6;

$total = $settings['someMathFunction']($var->price, $settings['figure']);
```

This is pretty horrible code though. Is there ever going to be a case where you aren't going to divide? If not then [Y.A.G.N.I](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it)