# Conditional string i.e. '>' to an object i.e. >

Tags: php

```
$gted = (object)'&gt;';
if(200 $gted 300){
    echo 'wow it worked';
}else{
    echo 'no it didnt work';
}
```

I am trying to convert the '>' to a conditional > to use in an `if` statement. Thanks.

Comment: What do you wish to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Can you not just do `if(200 > 300)`? Your question doesn't make a lot of sense

Comment: This is in no way possible. Why don't you try a simple switch/case?

Comment: Operators are defined in the language. Even if you cant multiple dereference using strings you can't use that to get an operator. You might use eval but `eval is evil`. I suggest you just use if-else.

Answer (score 3):

This will not work the way that you have it. Variables cannot be be interpreted as operators in PHP directly, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263311/using-a-variable-as-an-operator).

Even if you could interpret a variable as an operator, what you have in your string 'object' is *not* a greater-than sign, it is an HTML entity that, when interpreted *as* an HTML entity, yields something that *looks* like a greater-than sign.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2552052/variable-operators-in-php) has some answers that include some workarounds for arithmetic operators which can be used to store results to be evaluated inside of an `if` statement.  As an example for use in this answer, I borrowed and slightly modified part of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2552109/697370) by @user187291 that uses [`create_function`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.create-function.php):

```
$operator = '+';
$func = create_function('$a,$b', "return \$a $operator \$b;");

$result = $func(5, 1);
echo $result;
```

The echo'd result would be `6`, as you would expect.  You could change what operator is being used so that the pseudo-anonymous function instead returns a boolean value which you could then plug into an `if` statement:

```
$operator = '>';
$func = create_function('$a,$b', "return \$a $operator \$b;");

$result = $func(200, 300);
if($result) {
    echo 'wow it worked';
} else {
    echo 'no it didnt work';
}
```

Except in extreme and very specific circumstances that I cannot currently imagine, I would not think this to be a good idea.