# Compare based on a stored variable

Tags: php, mysql, metaprogramming

Maybe there is a topic about this, but I coudn't find.

I'm storing in a database a comparative operator and a target value, like:

```
$target_value_1 => 1000

$operator => greather_than_or_equal
```

Is there a way of using those operators in a variable like:

```
if ($variable1 $operator $target_value_1){

    // Some code

}
```

Working with PHP and MySQL.

Thanks

Comment: Possible Dupe? [Using a variable as an operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263311/using-a-variable-as-an-operator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what are you building but you can sort this by simply creating a `check($operator, $var1, $var2)` function along these lines :

```
function check($operator, $val1, $val2) {
    switch ($operator) {
    case 'greather_than_or_equal':
        return $val1 >= $val2;
        break;
    case 'greather_than':
        return $val1 > $val2;
        break;
    case 'operator_name':
        //return your condition goes here;
        break;
    default:
        return false;
        break;
    }
}
```

And use it : `if (check($operator, $value1, $value2)) { /* your code */ }`

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I was thinking of getting around this way, but first I'd like to check if there wasn't a shortter and cleaner way to do it.

Comment: Say you have defined the function `greather_than_or_equal($a, $b) {return $a>=$b;}`, you can do use is later as `if ($operator($variable1, $target_value_1)) { ..` you can define your operators as functions this way but it's way less cleaner/readable in my opinion.